# Dynamically loading content in c# asp.net mvc 4 using javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm working on a website where the owner has exhibitions which he can add, edit and delete. The exhibitions are showed per year, once clicking on the 'Read more' button. I'm running into a weird problem with my pages, since I'm loading the content in a new div once clicking on 'Read more' and I need an unique identifier for this div. I'm using `id="@Year here"` to identify this div, however I run into this problem:

[image]

As you can see, it is not loading properly. I have the following code to load in all exhibitions per group:

```
@if(Model.Exhibitions.Count() > 0)
{
<h3 style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">@Model.Year</h3>
<table class="extable">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 15%">@Translations.EXHIBITIONSTARTDATE</th>
        <th style="width: 15%">@Translations.EXHIBITIONENDDATE</th>
        <th style="width: 15%">@Translations.EXHIBITIONEVENT</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">@Translations.EXHIBITIONDESCRIPTION</th>
        <th style="width: 15%">@Translations.GALLERY</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (Exhibition item in Model.Exhibitions)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Exhibition", item)
}

</table>

}

<div class="more-exhi" id="@Model.Next"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    $('.more-exhi#@Model.Year').attr('class', '');
    $('.show-more').attr('data-year', '@Model.Next');
}) ();
</script>
```

@Model.Year is the year being send to the controller (for example, 2014). @Model.Next is the next existing year with exhibitions in descending order (for example, 2010). However the code is above is not working right, and I am not sure why. This is my javascript once someone clicks on the button 'Read more':

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

    var div = $('#exhibitions');

    div.find('.show-more').click(function () {
        div.find('.more-exhi').hide().load('@Url.Action("Exhibitions", "Exhibition")', { year: $(this).attr('data-year') } ).fadeIn('1500');
        div.find('.show-less').show();
    });

})();
</script>
```

Could someone help me fixing this problem? I think I'm overseeing a problem here, as this shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change this line of code into:

```
 $('.more-exhi#' + @Model.Year).attr('class', '');
```

:)

Comment: No prob, @KevinVoorn!